# Removing duplicates from two textfiles using perl (this 2 text files are output of the other perl script)

Tags: perl

have written one perl script which gives two textfile as output. The first text file contains value like below, 0900 0915 0930 0945 1000 1015 1030 1045 1100 ~ and the second text file contains values like this, 0900 0915 0930 1000 1015 1030 1100 I want to compare two files and remove the match values and display the mismatch value in a textfile.The output should be 0945 1045  I tried with the below code,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$\="\n";

open my $fh1, '<', 'textfile1.txt' or die $!;
open my $fh2, '<', 'textfile2.txt' or die $!;
open my $out, '>', 'output.txt' or die $!;

chomp(my @arr1=<$fh1>);
chomp(my @arr2=<$fh2>);

foreach my $x (@arr1){
        print $out $x if (!grep (/^\Q$x\E$/,@arr2));
}

close $fh1;
close $fh2;
close $out;
```

But Im getting textfile1 contents as output which is not expected output. If I create a new textfiles with the same values manually and executes it works fine. Since this text files are output of my perl script. I think its not taking this as input properly. Could someone please help me on this?

Comment: text file values are in new lines or in a single line?

Comment: Hi Shah, Thanks for the reply. Text files values are in new lines oly.. Im not able to paste it here. If i paste it showing the values in single line.

Comment: Try my solution below. Otherwise it works fine for me with `my @arr1=qw(0900 0915 0930 0945 1000 1015 1030 1045 1100);` and `my @arr2=qw(0900 0915 0930 1000 1015 1030 1100);`

Comment: Can u pls tel me how to move the values of text file to an array. I used to use command like this @array='cat textfile.txt` but how to use qw in this case? Could you pls tell me?

Comment: Your method of reading file is also fine in question. I just created array with `qw` for testing and not open files. Please see my solution below and comment there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your input file doesn't contain those numbers in separate lines, otherwise your code works just fine.

Try adding following lines before foreach loop

```
@arr1 = split (' ', join (' ', @arr1) );
@arr2 = split (' ', join (' ', @arr2) );
```

Comment: Hi Shah, This code works fine.. Thanks alot.. :) If we want to remove the unmatch value and display only the value which matches, in that case ?

Comment: @Dora just remove negation `!` from `grep` i.e. `print $out $x if (grep (/^\Q$x\E$/,@arr2));`

Comment: Wow.. thats great.. It works fine.. Thank u sooooo much shah !! :)

Comment: @Dora you're welcome. glad that it worked for you. It seems you are new to this site. If any answer worked for you, consider accepting it by clicking on hollow green tick mark on the upper left corner of answer. You may want to read [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page soon.